# How to put a xml file in localhost?

Tags: windows-8

I am trying the windows 8 live tiles program. In this application, i want to place xml files on local host.
 like `var urls =  new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://localhost/tile1.xml")`,

but i dont know how to place in local host please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the XML file in the root direcory of the web site listening on localhost's port 80. If it's IIS, the directory is probably `C:\InetPub\wwwroot`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.but i dont have InetPub folder in C:/ directory.what can i do?

Comment: Well, it depends on what web server you have. If you don't know what web server you have (or don't have one), that's a topic for maybe http://superuser.com.

Comment: Thank you very much.i will search.if i have any doubts i will ask.Thank you